# How can I make first number of phone number cannot be zero?

Tags: javascript, html, numbers

My html like this :

```
<input type="number" />
```

I had validation number, so user only input number. I want the first digit to be non-zero

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use text input with a pattern attribute:

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
  Phone Number: <input type="text" name="phone_number" pattern="[1-9][0-9]+" title="Phone number without a leading zero" required="required">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

and to use with number you can use this:

```html
<input type="number" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/^0/g, '');" >
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this help. It really saved me a lot of hours searching for javascript codes